# How to import dmp file to oracle DB via SqlDeveloper or CMD in windows?

Tags: oracle, import, impdp, oracle-dump

I have an Oracle dump file that got exported from an unfamiliar database.
I need to import it to my Oracle DB with either SqlDeveloper or command line in windows.
When using Data Pump Import Wizard in SqlDeveloper I'm getting the below error:
`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

When using the CMD I'm getting the below error:
`ORA-39002: invalid operation ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file. ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536 ORA-29283: invalid file operation`

My command line:

`impdp USER/password DUMPFILE=c:\folder_name\file_name.dmp TABLES=All LOG=dump_log.log`

I tried different variations and each time the same error.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is missing the directory or the files in the proper directory on the db server. The default is `DATA_PUMP_DIR` which can be found from the DB as follow.

```
SQL>  SELECT directory_name, directory_path FROM dba_directories
  2   WHERE directory_name='DATA_PUMP_DIR';
DIRECTORY_NAME    DIRECTORY_PATH
_________________ _________________________________________________________________
DATA_PUMP_DIR     /opt/oracle/admin/ORCL/dpdump/8967C87908440D12E053020011AC6F8A
```

To make a new directory:

CREATE DIRECTORY MY_DIR AS 'c:\folder_name\';

Then add the directory and remove the path from the file parameter.

```
impdp USER/password directory=MY_DIR  DUMPFILE=file_name.dmp TABLES=All LOG=dump_log.log
```

ref:

IMPDP >  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL907

Create directory > https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5007.htm#SQLRF01207

Comment: Tried it, now getting this error: ORA-39002: invalid operation ORA-39166: Object SYSTEM.ALL was not found or could not be exported or imported.

Comment: Now, you seem to have a permission issue. Who was the export done as and who was is the import trying to be done as ?

Comment: Thank you Kris, the user that did the export is not from my DB and I don't know much about it. The user who's doing the import is just the SYSTEM user which i thought has all the permissions, but might be wrong... anything we can do to resolve this?

Comment: You can try the SQLFILE param to get a list of what's in the file. 
 SQLFILE=expfull.sql  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#sthref354

Comment: I think you need to remove the "TABLES=All" argument from the impdp script above.

Comment: Thank you, i will review the file see if it can help us. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you also ultddave, after doing that and also running specific grants to my user i was able to import the DB.